# How to return a value if it is found in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to find some value in the nested list, and if it is present, I want to return a particular field as my output.

This is my input list:

```
set1 = [
    {'type': 'customer',  'value': '93227729', 'field': '1Ax6EsCM'},
    {'type': 'customer', 'value': '1234', 'field': 'abc'},
    {'type': 'customer', 'value': '78654', 'field': 'abc'}
]
```

I want to find the word `'abc'` in this list, and if it present, then I want to output the corresponding `"value"` attribute. In case multiple values are found, the output should be a concatenation of all corresponding values, with commas.

In the above list, after searching 'abc', the output I need is:  `1234,78654`

I have tried for and if operators, but the code is returning all of the values:

```
set1 = [
    {'type': 'customer',  'value': '93227729', 'field': '1Ax6EsCM'}, 
    {'type': 'customer', 'value': '1234', 'field': 'abc'},
    {'type': 'customer', 'value': '78654', 'field': 'abc'}
]
print(set1)
val ='abc'

for data in set1:
    if (val in g for g in data):
        print(data['value'])
```

Comment: Do you only want to check `field` for 'abc' or all entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
[x['value'] for x in set1 if x['field'] == search_word]
```

**Example**:

```
set1 = [{'type': 'customer',  'value': '93227729', 'field': '1Ax6EsCM'}, {'type': 'customer', 'value': '1234', 'field': 'abc'},{'type': 'customer', 'value': '78654', 'field': 'abc'}]
search_word = 'abc'

print([x['value'] for x in set1 if x['field'] == search_word])
# ['1234', '78654']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, maybe less elegant and smart than that of Austin, is:

```
set1=[{'type': 'customer',  'value': '93227729', 'field': '1Ax6EsCM'},{'type': 'customer', 'value': '1234', 'field': 'abc'},{'type': 'customer', 'value': '78654', 'field': 'abc'}]

print(set1)
val ='abc'
for data in set1:
    if data['field'] == val:
        print(data['value'])
```

Or you can define a list and add the various elements to it:

```
tmp = []
val ='abc'
for data in set1:
    if data['field'] == val:
        tmp.append(data['value'])

print(tmp) 
#output: ['1234', '78654']
```